# Change the directory name and fastq file name with snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I would like to change the folder names and the names of the read files. From here I found something similar ([Move and rename files from multiple folders using snakemake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574413/move-and-rename-files-from-multiple-folders-using-snakemake?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

```
workdir: "/path/to/workdir/"

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

sample_file = StringIO("""fastq sampleID
BOB_1234/fastq/BOB_1234.R1.fastq.gz TAG_1/fastq/TAG_1.R1.fastq.gz
BOB_1234/fastq/BOB_1234.R2.fastq.gz TAG_1/fastq/TAG_1.R2.fastq.gz
BOB_3421/fastq/BOB_3421.R1.fastq.gz TAG_2/fastq/TAG_2.R1.fastq.gz
BOB_3421/fastq/BOB_3421.R2.fastq.gz TAG_2/fastq/TAG_2.R2.fastq.gz""")

df = pd.read_table(sample_file, sep="\s+", header=0)
sampleID = df.sampleID
fastq = df.fastq

rule all:
    input:
       expand("{sample}", sample=df.sampleID)

rule move_and_rename_fastqs:
    input: fastq = lambda w: df[df.sampleID == w.sample].fastq.tolist()
    output: "{sample}"
    shell:
        """echo mv {input.fastq} {output}"""
```

I can an error:

```
MissingOutputException in line 19 of snakefile:
Job Missing files after 5 seconds:
TAG_1/fastq/TAG_1.R1.fastq.gz
```

Comment: Your move_and_rename_fastqs is just echoing the mv command, not executing it.  Remove the `echo` and try again.  You can run snakemake with `-np` to get a dryrun with the commands that will run instead of putting echos in your shell directives

Comment: How can  one be so stupid... :/ thanks a lot... it is working